# How to access Windows 8 Tablet via Remote Desktop from PC

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, tablet, windows-tabletpc

I have a Windows 8.1 Tablet and a Win7 Desktop. I've tried to access the Tablet via the Remote Desktop app from my PC for easier configuration but it couldn't connect. I could ping the device, so network state was fine so far. Remote desktop access is allowed according to the "Remote" tab in advanced system settings. I suppose I forgot something pretty simple, but have currently no idea what. As the Windows 8.1 is not the "Pro" Edition one can't select users to be allowed, but I'm not sure if this is important.

I meanwhile ensured that the network is marked as work/private so there should be no rule preventing access (I can't find one), but it seems this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Home Editions are not allowed to being connected via Remote Desktop even as an admin account. 
Only remote assistance is allowed, which does not enable you to connect without a local user input.

Comment: Can I simulate that in my local network ?

Comment: yes of course, but I might not understand you correctly?!

Comment: I've never used remote assistance, so I'm not sure whether it works without interaction to a remote server in a local network like VNC using a completely internal LAN connection. But while thinking about I could run VNC on my tablet so it would also work but might not be as fast as RDP.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the credentials of an administrator account on the host computer, you shouldn't have problems connecting. Read this for details: [How to enable remote desktop connections](http://www.7tutorials.com/enabling-remote-desktop-connections-windows-7)

Comment: Hi celalalt, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True. For the problem in question I would suggest to check if any firewall rules are preventing the remote desktop connection.